# Read and Write Operation in perl script

Tags: linux, perl

I am Newbie to Perl script.

I want to do a read and write operation on a file. I will open a file in read and write mode (+<), and will write into a file. Now, I want read the file whatever I have written to it previously. Below is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

`touch file.txt`; #Create a file as opening the file in +< mode
open (OUTFILE, "+<file.txt") or die "Can't open file : $!";

print OUTFILE "Hello, welcome to File handling operations in perl\n"; #write into the file

$line = <OUTFILE>; #read from the file

print "$line\n"; #display the read contents.
```

When I am displaying the read contents it's showing a blank line. But the file "file.txt" has the data

```
Hello, welcome to File handling operations in perl
```

Why am I not able to read the contents. Whether my code is wrong or am I missing something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your filehandle position is located after the line you have written. Use the [`seek`](http://p3rl.org/seek) function to move the "cursor" back to the top before reading again.

An example, with some extra comments:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

# use some recommended safeguards
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = 'file.txt';
`touch $filename`;

# use indirect filehandle, and 3 argument form of open
open (my $handle, "+<", $filename) or die "Can't open file $filename : $!";
# btw good job on checking open sucess!

print $handle "Hello, welcome to File handling operations in perl\n";

# seek back to the top of the file
seek $handle, 0, 0;

my $line = <$handle>;

print "$line\n";
```

If you will be doing lots of reading and writing you may want to try (and not everyone suggests it) using [`Tie::File`](http://p3rl.org/Tie%3a%3aFile) which lets you treat a file like an array; line access by line number (newline written automatically).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

# use some recommended safeguards
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;

my $filename = 'file.txt';
tie my @file, 'Tie::File', $filename
  or die "Can't open/tie file $filename : $!";

# note file not emptied if it already exists

push @file, "Hello, welcome to File handling operations in perl";
push @file, "Some more stuff";

print "$file[0]\n";
```

Comment: Interesting one joel. I will use this in my script.

Comment: okie. But i just need to save it in a file and read the same without using seek and reopening the file by switching modes. I just need to know this. Will Tie::File affects my script if i am storing a large data into the file.

Comment: `Tie::File` just does the seek for you, its all under the hood. As it is still file io, size of the data shouldn't matter too much, except that it has to search for the newline markers. Unless you have some better mechanism than that, it would be the same as you searching for some line.

Answer (score 0):

This is a seemingly common beginner mistake. Most often you will find that reading and writing to the same file, while possible, is not worth the trouble. As Joel Berger says, you can `seek` to the beginning of the file. You can also simply re-open the file. Seeking is not as straightforward as reading line by line, and will present you with difficulties.

Also, you should note, that creating an empty file beforehand is not required. Simply do:

```
open my $fh, ">", "file.txt" or die $!;
print $fh "Hello\n";
open $fh, "<", "file.txt" or die $!;
print <$fh>;
```

Note that:

- using `open` on the same file handle will automatically close it.
- I use three-argument open, and a lexical (defined by `my`) file handle, which is the recommended way.
- you do not need to add newline when printing a variable read in line by line mode, as it will already have a newline at the end. Or end of file.
- You can use `print <$fh>`, as the print statement is in list context, it will extract all the lines from the file handle (print the entire file).

If you only want to print one line, you can do:

```
print scalar <$fh>;  # put <$fh> in scalar context
```

Comment: Thanks TLP. I have a question. Can I reopen a file in different modes as many times as I require, such as in a while loop? Will it lead to any difficulties?

Comment: When you reopen a file handle, the old file handle is closed. It will not cause any difficulties, unless you create some. :) If you have a specific problem to solve, you should ask about that, rather than generic questions, though.

Comment: If you use more I/O operations, it will per definition lead to more I/O operations, yes. This is, however, not a problem, and you will not find any great performance losses, unless you have a very large amount of operations. But in that case, you might think of other ways to optimize your code.

Comment: This is probably safer, especially if you are only going to "switch modes" a few times. Of course, I still contend that `seek` is technically the *right answer* for the original question :-)

Comment: @JoelBerger Yes, but the right answer is not always the right solution. =P